# dynamic validators and itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, validation

I have a bunch of dynamic validators that I create in my application.

I have an mxml which contains a s:DataGroup.
The DataGroup contains an itemRenderer.
In this itemRenderer, I have a combobox which I want to validate.

I perform the validation like this ont the creationComplete of the itemRenderer:

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var condition:Condition = data as Condition;
    condition.validator.source = valuesComboBox.textInput;
    condition.validator.property= "text";
}
```

Of course, when I do this, the itemrenderer is recycling, and the validator appears in places in which i do not want it to.

Anybody have any idea how i can work around this problem?

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 2):

Why not to validate `selectedItem` of `ComboBox` and use `ComboBox` as a source:

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var condition:Condition = data as Condition;
    condition.validator.source = valuesComboBox;
    condition.validator.property= "selectedItem";
}
```